# Which jar to use for connecting to MS SQL server

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc, mssql-jdbc

Can some one please guide me to understand which jar file i need to include in my application to be able to set up a jdbc connection with ms sql server.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

sqljdbc.jar and sqljdbc4.jar class library files to be used depending on your preferred Java Runtime Environment (JRE) settings. For more information about which JAR file to choose, see [System Requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/system-requirements-for-the-jdbc-driver) for the JDBC Driver.

Downloads links and more information can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server).

Answer (score 6):

You can use [jtds](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/) jar, you will also need to add the dll/so to you java library path.

**EDIT:**
[More recent release](https://github.com/milesibastos/jTDS/releases)

Comment: There are more recent versions on github: https://github.com/milesibastos/jTDS/releases

Comment: @Abhishek - [Microsoft's JDBC driver for SQL Server](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc) is now open source as well (MIT license).

Answer (score 4):

The Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver version 2.0 provides **sqljdbc.jar**  and **sqljdbc4.jar** class library files to be used depending on your preferred Java Runtime Environment (JRE) settings.

**sqljdbc4.jar** class library requires a *Java Runtime Environment* (**JRE**) of version 6.0 or later.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft started publishing their Driver JARs to the central Maven repo in 2017.
See [Maven Search](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.microsoft.sqlserver%20AND%20a:mssql-jdbc&core=gav) for the available versions.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.0.jre10</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=99B21B65-E98F-4A61-B811-19912601FDC9&displaylang=en

MS JDBC Driver. Has documentation.

Comment: That version of the JDBC driver is very old (released over 9 years ago). Look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server) for more current information.

Comment: You make it sounds like giving a current answer more than 8 years ago (!) was bad.

Comment: No, I was just giving future readers a heads-up that the link (which still works) takes them to a download page for an old version of the driver. A surprising number of mssql-jdbc questions are asked by people who are using an ancient version of the JDBC driver and don't even know it.